# Reading messages selectively from SQS Queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

There is a SQS Queue in which I am getting messages continuously. I need to read and process only those messages that came in the last 24 hours. The messages which would be coming in currently should be processed on the next day. `Timestamp` is stored in the body of the message.

Is it possible to read messages selectively from the SQS queue. For instance, read only those messages whose `timestamp` value is greater than the previous day's timestamp but less than the current timestamp (current timestamp is the time at which this job is running)?

Comment: Can you provide more details of your use case and the reason for needing this behaviour? We might be able to suggest alternate approaches rather than using an SQS queue.

Comment: Message queue services name as such because it work in sequential order. Messages that are not consumed will go back to the queue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Amazon SQS `ReceiveMessages` command returns a message (or a batch of messages) from the queue. The messages are in approximately FIFO (first in-first out) order but this is not guaranteed.

**There is no way to selectively retrieve messages.** It is not possible to use the contents of a message, a message attribute nor message metadata to limit the messages returned. It's basically popping a message off a stack.